# Is a language *engine* the same as a language *implementation*?

Tags: compilers, interpreters

(This may just be a terminology clarification question.)

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)

> A language usually has at least one implementation in the form of a compiler or interpreter, allowing programs written in the language to be executed.

And reading the [page on programming language implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_implementation):

> In computer programming, a programming language implementation is a system for executing computer programs.

This page also gives CPython and PyPy as examples. So I think we can safely conclude that those are implementations.

Searching for "CPython engine" or "PyPy engine" gives me very few results. So are CPython and PyPy "engines"?

But if we then look at [V8](https://v8.dev/docs), both their docs and [the Wikipedia page for V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) use the term "engine" but the docs also state V8 *implements* the ECMAScript standard. Is this because V8 is more than just an implementation of ECMAScript? Would it be more precise to say that V8 *contains* an implementation of ECMAScript?

Or could it be that these projects have chosen to use one term over another and the communities around them have followed suit? It kinda feels like "implementation" is the more computer science-y term for it and "engine" was chosen by V8 to sound less daunting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of the phrase "language engine" before, so I don't think you need to worry about knowing that phrase.  Perhaps it is used in certain communities, such as browsers.  From context, it sounds like a Javascript engine is a subsystem of a browser that provides a Javascript interpreter/JIT plus interfaces to all of the browser APIs.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I could have phrased that a little better maybe: I don't see people using the term "language engine" but I do see people using the term "engine" for things that (to me) sound like language implementations. Wrt V8, I think it's really *just* an implementation according to the docs, and does not provider browser API interfaces or other extras.

Comment: @NielsBom, OK.  Maybe it is as simple as you have stated: some people have used the word 'engine' to refer to something that could also be called a language implementation.